# JSONSmart parsing a whole array and getting each object?

Tags: java, json

An example JSON.

EDIT: I've put it on a pastebin because of how big the file is - http://pastebin.com/wdR2paBp

How would I get an Array of "objects", then iterate through it and get the name (i.e. "minecraft/sounds/dig/sand4.ogg") and the hash from each of these files?

### My attempts:

```
FileReader fr = new FileReader(location.getAbsolutePath());
JSONArray iIndexes = (JSONArray) parser.parse(fr);
```

- I've also tried making Objects a JSONObject then making it a JSONArray then using a for loop to get every object, but I get a NPE or a ClassCast Exception (for the atttempt before this one).

Comment: It's not valid JSON.  The {}'s don't balance.  It is certainly not a JSON array.

Comment: I've added the file on a pastebin, could you try re check, that was just a snippet.

Comment: @NeilDerno, if the `objects` is supposed to be an array, its content should be inside **[** and **]**. I think your text is not a valid JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have there is a JSON object, not a JSON array.  Conceptually, you can treat it as a set of name/value pairs, but according to the JSON specification, the NV pairs are not ordered; i.e. it is a set, not a list.

There is no standard way to turn that `JSONObject` into a `JSONArray`.  Casting won't work, and the `JSONObject` doesn't have a method to do the conversion.  And certainly, there is no way using JSONSmart to preserve the *apparent order* of the NV pairs in your source file / string.  (Which is a good thing, IMO, because the order *shouldn't* mean anything.)

If you want to iterate the NV pairs, the best way to do it is to use the `entrySet` method to get the JSONObject's entries as a `Set` ... and then iterate the set.  (The JSONSmart version of `JSONObject` is a subclass of `HashMap`.)

---

Now if set of entries in "objects" is supposed to be ordered, then you have designed your JSON scheme incorrectly.  You should be using a JSON array (using the `[...]` JSON syntax) and the elements need to be restructured as objects; e.g.

```
  [ {
      "name": "realms/lang/de_DE.lang",
      "hash": "10a54fc66c8f479bb65c8d39c3b62265ac82e742",
      "size": 8112
    },
    {
      "name": "realms/lang/cy_GB.lang",
      "hash": "14cfb2f24e7d91dbc22a2a0e3b880d9829320243",
      "size": 7347
    },
    etcetera
  ]
```

When you parse that using JSONSmart you will get a `JSONArray`.